# FEniCS implementation of Maxwell equations for a dipole antenna

Tags: finite-element, fenics, electromagnetism

someone knows where I can find a FEniCS implementation of Maxwell equations for a dipole or other type of antenna? I mean a dipole antenna with an arbitrary geometry of every 'leg' in the dipole.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic in this site. It better suits [FEniCS Discourse site](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/).

Comment: I don't think so, I have seen plenty of questions about FEniCS here, take a look at the related question on the right panel.